# php json decode array of objects in laravel

Tags: json, laravel

How to extract only `15` from `[{"1":"15"}]` in Laravel controller?

```
$var = array();
$mku = $mark->examMark;
$var[] = json_decode($mku, true);
```

I have tried using the above code but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
$value = json_decode($mku, true)[1];
```

Comment: Nop.am not geting any values.

Comment: Please show results of `dd(json_decode($mku, true));`

Comment: Here, the call to the controller function is made from angular js function. so from the controller we are returning the value back to the js function. Here dd($value) is not working

Comment: Then do `\Log::info('Result is: '.json_decode($mku, true));` and see for the result in `storage/logs/laravel.log`

Comment: @Cliffs so, it's json which contains json?  Just a guess, but try something like `json_decode(json_decode($mku, true), true)[1]` then.

Comment: @Cliffs so, what does logging of `json_decode(json_decode($mku, true), true)` show?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$decoded = json_decode($mku, true)[0][1];
```